# Traefik and multiple domains some with letsencrypt and some from SSL provider

Tags: docker, ssl, docker-compose, traefik

I'm configuring multiple domains in docker-compose and to route traffic I would like to use Traefik. He has very nice ability to create and manage letsencrypt certificate but some of my domains have enterprise SSL certificates from ssl provider (comodo).
My question is it possible to configure traefik such that it will be generate, manage letsencrypt certificates and at the same time he will be handle "static" certificates from another providers, e.g. comodo?